# Is there an easy, recommended way to retrieve human-readable values from CSS3 transform: matrix3d?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transforms

I have a cube and I want to apply some transform:

`$("#cube-wrapper").css({transform: "rotateX(10deg)"})`

Then I want to apply some more transforms - I would like to retrieve current transform value and append a new one:

`$("#cube-wrapper").css({transform: "rotateX(10deg) rotateY(20deg)"})`

Unfortunately I cannot retrieve human-readable version of the transform, the way how Chrome and jQuery presents it:

`matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.984808, 0.173648, 0, 0, -0.173648, 0.984808, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)`

I could potentially do some reading, upgrade my math knowledge and solve some equations *(that may have multiple solutions)*, here are two great resources:

- http://franklinta.com/2014/09/08/computing-css-matrix3d-transforms/
- http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/

[image]

---

The question remains - is there an easy, recommended way to retrieve human-readable values from CSS3 transform: matrix3d?

Comment: There is no easy answer to get all values in a human readable format. In [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450835/get-3d-css-rotation-value-from-matrix3d-with-javascript) you'll see how to get the rotation degrees. In comments to that question I had linked a few pages which you may find useful.

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30583749/5545315

Comment: Thank you! These links are exactly what I've been looking for... Close and mark as duplicate :)